# Network gone after purchasing in InApp Billing Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have weird situation in InApp Billing android.

I have few categories where I have to purchase each category then consume them so that they have to be purchased again(Consumable Products).And I am using IAB 3 version.

Now immediately after purchasing the category and in between Success Message receiving, if I  turn-off Wi-fi then I get an email notification that I have purchased.But when I try to purchase the same category I get "Error as Item Already Owned ". I even tried to query the purchased items getPurchases() but didn't get info on non-consumed products.

Let me know is there any way to know the information of categories purchased but not consumed?

Thanks and Regards,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

> tl;dr : Query for purchased when app start (or resume) and consume product
>   if necessary.

After purchase, you have to send consumption request for item you purchased so google play can make it available for purchase again. Now, I believe you issue is when you turn-off wi-fi after purchasing and before receiving success message, you disrupt consumption request process. So the product is purchased but not consumed.

Ideal solution would be, query for purchased item every time app start-up or resume. You can do that because purchased data is locally cached by Google Play's In-App billing service and doing so you app will always reflect current user's in-app product ownership info.

Every code snippet necessary for this solution is available in in-app billing sample app and you can also get it from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#QueryPurchases).

Comment: mIsPremium = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM); is returning false though I got mail confirmation of purchase order (In case of network gone after purchasing and Payment Successful).

Comment: I assume you do that when app start-up. Are you sure SKU you used to check is the one you used to buy ?

Comment: Yes I am sure its the same SKU.After purchasing the SKU I immediately consuming the product.The problem occurs if the network goes in between.